# How can I generate a set of coordinates for a circle that avoids serveral specified areas?

Tags: javascript, math, 2d

I'm working on a 2D game, and the safespawn isn't great. The current system gets a random coordinate and checks for collision, trying again if the position collides with another object. After 15 failed attempts, it will give up and spawn on top of another object. I am wondering if there is a way to create a formula to calculate a position outside of an array of positions. For example, say I have this array:

```
var coveredArea = [
    {x: 200, y: 100, r: 50}
    {x: 100, y: 300, r: 50}
    {x: 300, y: 200, r: 50}
];
```

For a visual representation, let's say the canvas looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cZXM.png

I want to make a formula to calculate a position outside of these objects without random guess and check. Is this possible? I would hope to get a base idea here that will steer me in the right direction if a solution is too complex to be given away.

Comment: `position outside of these ranges` what do you mean by that?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz The objects in the array are objects in the game, and I want to get coordinates that do not collide with the ones in the array.

Comment: Coordinate is a point. So collision with a point is simple equality check. Isn't it

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I added a visual representation.

Comment: One option would be to generate a random X coordinate, iterate through the current objects to see which Y values would be non-intersecting, and then choose a random element from the valid Y values.

Answer (score 0):

If scene dimensions are resonable, prohibited objects do not vary position frequently and you have to execute many queries, the simplest and fastest is map approach:

Make bitmap, fill it by black and draw all the objects filled with white color (if you need to distinguish different objects, draw each by specific color #000001, #000002 etc).

Then just check for pixel color in needed coordinates.

If you have specific radius of circle (not just point), then use wide pen for figure borders (lineWidth =2*R+1, lineJoin = round)